# Is there a compiler setting to control how floating point literals are typed in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, floating-point, literals

While the the case for `e` works by default I would like to change the default casting of the literal `0.1` to allow the `r` to work without any code modifications. Is this possible through a compiler option, compiler directive, or anything else?

```
procedure Test;
var
  s : Single;
  r : Real;
  d : Double;
  e : Extended;
begin
  s := 0.1;
  if (s = 0.1) then ShowMessage('s matched'); // fail

  r := 0.1;
  if (r = 0.1) then ShowMessage('r matched'); // fail

  d := 0.1;
  if (d = 0.1) then ShowMessage('d matched'); // fail

  e := 0.1;
  if (e = 0.1) then ShowMessage('e matched'); // pass
end;
```

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.1  And why do you expect `if AVariable = 0.1` to work at all?

Comment: In general, a comparison with floating point will usually end in tears. While not being a direct answer, Arnaud is right about that and the typical alternative.

Comment: The question is not about comparing as I understand it. It is the type of the literal.

Comment: I said not a direct answer, just allowing for the fact that question defines the test using compares. A good chance that the final reasoning for this is compares too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no compiler switch that does what you wish. The issue is that a floating point literal is represented as a 10 byte extended precision value by the 32 bit Windows compiler. And because `0.1` is not exactly representable, that is not equal to the 8 byte double precision representation of `0.1`.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions) says:

> If constantExpression is a real, its type is **Extended**.

You can however achieve the desired result by using a typed constant. For example:

```
const 
  TenthDouble: Double = 0.1;
var
  d: Double;
....
d := 0.1;
if d = TenthDouble then
  ....
```

By using a typed constant we are able to force the compiler to make the constant be the 8 byte double precision representation of `0.1`.

Comment: I would just add to this that extended is aliased to Double on 64 bit which can further complicate the situation because it results in different behavior on 32 bit and 64 bit. The whole constant = extended is nuts. We always declare floating point constants as typed doubles because of this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the casting, but the comparison itself, and how floating points are encoded.  See e.g. [this blog article, which deals explicitely with the 0.1 value](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). In short, this 0.1 value is not encoded as 0.1 but as 0.100000001490116119384765625 (single) or 0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834045 (double) in the IEEE-754 format...

In fact, the following line

```
  if (s = 0.1) then ShowMessage('s matched'); // fail
```

is compiled (at least under x87 i.e. Delphi 32-bit) as

```
  s := 0.1;
  e := 0.1;
  if s=e then
    writeln('ok');
```

And in the IEEE standard encoding, 0.1 is not stored the same as extended or single precision:

```
  s := 0.1;
  e := 0.1;
  writeln('s=',BinToHex(@s, SizeOf(s)));
  writeln('e=',BinToHex(@e, SizeOf(e)));
  //s=CDCCCC3D
  //e=CDCCCCCCCCCCCCCCFB3F
```

Whereas for 0.5 there is no rounding problem:

```
  s := 0.5;
  e := 0.5;
  writeln('s=',BinToHex(@s, SizeOf(s)));
  writeln('e=',BinToHex(@e, SizeOf(e)));
  if s=e then
    writeln(ok); // it works!
  // s=0000003F
  // e=0000000000000080FE3F
```

You can force the comparison as such:

```
var s, s2: single;

  s := 0.1;
  s2 := 0.1;
  if s = s2 then
    writeln('ok');
```

But anyway, to properly compare float values, the `SameValue()` methods of the `Math.pas` unit may be used, with an appropriate epsilon.

Comment: Don't think SameValue is to be recommended

Comment: It is not perfect, but it is better than plain = for sure. So not recommended, but at least mentioned.

Comment: FWIW, for the comparison, one of the values has to be converted, usually to the more precise type. So what really happens is that the literal (to Extended?) to Single to Extended conversion gives a different result than the direct literal to Extended conversion.

Comment: @Arnaud A common fallacy is that equality should never be used with floating point values. You don't know enough yet to recommend SameValue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just know enough patronizing from you, for sure.

Comment: Turn it into a problem with an individual if you like, but how can you know what the motivation behind the comparison is? It has not been stated. The problem with `SameValue`, or anything of its ilk, is the choice of tolerance. For a great many problems it is hard, often impossible to choose a reasonable tolerance. But it's all too easy to try something like `SameValue`, see that it works for limited inputs, but not realise that there are inputs where it won't give the desired behaviour. At least that is my experience based on 20 years working with floating point.

Comment: I never said anything else than that, speaking about the "appropriate epsilon"... which is indeed hard to tune as appropriate! If we count the years of programming, *you* become very individual, and should know that years don't matter about social skills - please download your update patch. ;)

Comment: @Arnaud I don't think that's the problem. If you don't like your answer being criticised on its technical merits I think that the issue is not at my end.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know. The x87 coprocessor default works in extended, so the compiler adapts.

Note that if you compile this program for 64-bit r,d and e match (probably because on 64-bit real=double=extended). 64-bit code does not use x87 for this but SSE2 as per 64-bit ABI.

Comment: It's not the x87 coprocessor so much as the compiler. It transforms 0.1 into a ten byte extended value.

Comment: @David is this conversion to a ten byte extended documented? Is it ever not the case? I am trying to decide between using your const d: Double = 0.1 approach vs using extended as the preferred floating point data type when comparisons to literals is required

Comment: It is documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions which is now in my answer. I'd be wary of using Extended, but I've no idea what you are trying to do. Your question is easy to answer but nobody can give you advice with confidence because we don't know what the underlying problem is.

Comment: It would be interesting to check the arm compiler. Older arms prefer single over double.

Comment: The documentation says that the literal is Extended which is Double on ARM

Comment: Adding to what David wrote: The type and value of of the literal are determined by the compiler, at compile time. And that is done using the x87 CPU. of course the compiler knows that on certain platforms, Extended is Double, but the setting on ARM has no influence on this, as that could only influence runtime behaviour.

Comment: @Rudy the compiler doesn't have to use floating point to compile floating point literals.

Comment: I say that because some ARM fpu's only do single, or have half the double performance as single. The x86/x87/x86_64 default of always converting to the largest type might backfire. But maybe it is not important in Delphi's case, since its arm offerings only target the top of the market.

Comment: @David: I'd expect the compiler to have a StrToFloat-like (strtod-like) routine, and these generally do use FP. Since the compiler is compiled with C++Builder (and assembler), it would not surprise me at all.

Comment: Not just that, it must also do constant evaluation and propagation  (e.g. const s= 10*1.0/0; )   Free Pascal has long been unable to crosscompile from non-x86 to x86 because the x86 compiler uses 10-byte extended, which didn't exist on non-x86. Afaik it is now done in soft-fpu.

Comment: @rudy It's not the compiler of the compiler that matters here, rather it's the runtime library. The reference implementation is David Gay's strtod and yes I think that does use floating point for some of its work.

Comment: @David: the compiler has to turn the string `0.1` into a binary value (8 or 10 byte). I doubt it uses David Gay's reference implementation for that, it simply uses the runtime that comes with C++Builder. And that uses x87 FP. And yes, David Gay's implementation uses FP for most values too (and a very limited BigInteger implementation for some).

Comment: @rudy Too bad it doesn't use the best